# YouTubePlayerView Picture in Picture android

Tags: java, android, youtubeplayer

[I'm making an application that implements the picture in picture functionality in android.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODjwX.jpg)

[When you click on the image, open a new activity with the picture in picture functionality.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2f9N.jpg)

[if I activate the function without giving play to the video, the functionality is done correctly, but when activating the picture in picture functionality when the video is playing, when entering picture in picture, the video stops playing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEy14.jpg)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCMnC.jpg)

Custom videoYoutubePlayer

```
public class VideoYoutubeView extends RelativeLayout {
private final static String TAG = VideoYoutubeView.class.getName();

@BindView(R.id.youtube_player)
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
@BindView(R.id.movie_play)
TextView btnPlay;
@BindView(R.id.movie_forward)
TextView btnForward;
@BindView(R.id.movie_back)
TextView btnBack;
@BindView(R.id.text_time_movie)
TextView textTimeVideo;
@BindView(R.id.seek_progress_movie)
SeekBar seekBarMovie;
@BindView(R.id.text_down)
TextView btnDown;

private YouTubePlayer mPlayer;
private Handler mHandler = null;
private OnPipListener onPipListener;

public VideoYoutubeView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VideoYoutubeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init(context);
}

public VideoYoutubeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.init(context);
}

public void setOnPipListener(@NonNull OnPipListener onPipListener) {
    this.onPipListener = onPipListener;
}

public void init(Context context) {
    View view = inflate(context, R.layout.youtube_view, this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
    this.setTypeFace(context);
    this.setUpVideoView();
}

private void setUpVideoView() {
    final OnClickListener listener = view -> {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.movie_play:
                toggleMovie();
                break;
            case R.id.movie_back:
                fastReview();
                break;
            case R.id.movie_forward:
                fastForward();
                break;
            case R.id.text_down:
                goToPip();
                break;
        }
    };
    this.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(listener);
    this.btnForward.setOnClickListener(listener);
    this.btnBack.setOnClickListener(listener);
    this.btnDown.setOnClickListener(listener);

}

private void goToPip() {
    if (this.onPipListener == null)
        return;
    this.onPipListener.goPiP();
}

public void hideControls() {
    this.btnPlay.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    this.btnDown.setVisibility(GONE);
    this.textTimeVideo.setVisibility(GONE);
    this.seekBarMovie.setVisibility(GONE);
}

public void showControls() {
    this.btnPlay.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    this.btnDown.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    this.textTimeVideo.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    this.seekBarMovie.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}

private void fastForward() {

}

private void fastReview() {

}

private void toggleMovie() {
    if (this.mPlayer == null)
        return;
    if (this.mPlayer.isPlaying())
        moviePause();
    else
        moviePlay();
}

private void moviePlay() {
    if (this.mPlayer == null)
        return;
    this.mPlayer.play();
    adjustStateMovie();
}

private void moviePause() {
    if (this.mPlayer == null)
        return;
    this.mPlayer.pause();
    adjustStateMovie();
}

private void adjustStateMovie() {
    if (mPlayer == null)
        return;
    this.btnPlay.setText(mPlayer.isPlaying() ? R.string.iconPlay : R.string.iconPause);
}

private void setTypeFace(Context context) {
    this.btnPlay.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));
    this.btnBack.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));
    this.btnForward.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));
    this.btnDown.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));
}

public void initialize(String apiKey, String videoId) {
    this.youTubePlayerView.initialize(apiKey, getOnInitializedListener(videoId));
}

private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener getOnInitializedListener(String videoId) {
    return new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                            YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (null == youTubePlayer) return;
            mPlayer = youTubePlayer;
            currentTimeVideo();
            // Start buffering
            if (!wasRestored) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
            }
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
            youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
            // Add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdStarted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
                    setSeekValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoading() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onVideoEnded() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onVideoStarted() {
                    currentTimeVideo();

                }
            });

            youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPaused() {
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlaying() {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
                    currentTimeVideo();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopped() {
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationFailure: Error initialize video youtube.");
        }
    };
}

private void currentTimeVideo() {
    if (null == mPlayer) return;
    String formattedTime = Util.formatTimeVideo(mPlayer.getDurationMillis() - mPlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis());
    textTimeVideo.setText(formattedTime);
}

private void setSeekValue() {
    if (mPlayer == null)
        return;
    this.seekBarMovie.setMax(mPlayer.getDurationMillis());
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        currentTimeVideo();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        seekBarMovie.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis(), true);
    }
};

public interface OnPipListener {
    void goPiP();
}
```

}

Activity implement picture in picture functionality:

```
public class VideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

@BindView(R.id.movie_chat)
VideoYoutubeView movieChat;
private final PictureInPictureParams.Builder mPictureInPictureParamsBuilder =
        new PictureInPictureParams.Builder();
private VideoYoutubeView.OnPipListener onPipListener = (this::setUpPip);

public static Intent getCallIntent(Context context, String messageConversation) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoActivity.class);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    this.setUpView();
}

private void setUpView() {
    this.movieChat.initialize("", "JRfuAukYTKg");
    this.movieChat.setOnPipListener(onPipListener);
}

public void setUpPip() {
    if (movieChat == null)
        return;
    this.movieChat.hideControls();
    //Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(movieChat.getWidth(), movieChat.getHeight());
    Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(20, 10);
    mPictureInPictureParamsBuilder.setAspectRatio(aspectRatio).build();
    enterPictureInPictureMode(mPictureInPictureParamsBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig);
    if (!isInPictureInPictureMode) {
        // Show the video controls if the video is not playing
        if (movieChat != null /*&& !movieChat.isPlaying()*/) {
            movieChat.showControls();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Someone can help me in the implementation of this functionality with the YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi library?

Answer (score 0):

I think you also have to override onPause() in your activity -

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
// If called while in PIP mode, do not pause playback
  if (isInPictureInPictureMode()) {
     // Continue playback
     ...
  } else {
     // Use existing playback logic for paused Activity behavior.
     ...
  }
}
```

Referencing [Android Documentation for Picture-in-picture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture)